# DeserializationError: ['“F(view_count) + Value(1)” value must be an integer.']

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, race-condition

I am using Django 3.2

I am using F values to increment a field value (to avoid potential race conditions) - [as recommended in the offical docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#avoiding-race-conditions-using-f).

Here is a snippet of my code (section that throws exception):

```
  def __update_fields(self, interaction_type):

        if interaction_type == Engagement.VIEW:
            self.view_count = F('view_count') + 1
        #elif check which field needs updating ...

        self.save() # By the time we get here, the necessary field (NOTE: **SINGULAR** word 'field') would have been updated

        self.refresh_from_db()
```

I get this error:

> DeserializationError: ['“F(view_count) + Value(1)” value must be an integer.']: (poll.poll:pk=10) field_value was 'F(view_count) + Value(1)'

Here is the full stack trace:

```
Internal Server Error: //path/to/example
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/myproj/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1836, in to_python
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'F(view_count) + Value(1)'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/myproj/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/serializers/python.py", line 144, in Deserializer
    data[field.name] = field.to_python(field_value)
  File "/path/to/myproj/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1838, in to_python
    raise exceptions.ValidationError(
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“F(view_count) + Value(1)” value must be an integer.']

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/myproj/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/path/to/myproj/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/path/to/myproj/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/path/to/myproj/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/path/to/myproj/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py", line 107, in get
    context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
  File "/path/to/myproj/poll/views.py", line 513, in get_context_data
    poll.interact(self.request.user, Engagement.VIEW, self.request)
  File "/path/to/myproj/social/models.py", line 988, in interact
    self.__update_fields(interaction_type)
  File "/path/to/myproj/social/models.py", line 947, in __update_fields
    self.save()
  File "/path/to/myproj/poll/models.py", line 97, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/path/to/myproj/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 726, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "/path/to/myproj/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 774, in save_base
    post_save.send(
  File "/path/to/myproj/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 180, in send
    return [
  File "/path/to/myproj/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 181, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "/path/to/myproj/moderation/register.py", line 321, in post_save_handler
    moderated_obj = ModeratedObject.objects.get_for_instance(instance)
  File "/path/to/myproj/moderation/managers.py", line 73, in get_for_instance
    moderated_object = self.get(object_pk=instance.pk,
  File "/path/to/myproj/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/path/to/myproj/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 431, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/path/to/myproj/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 262, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/path/to/myproj/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/path/to/myproj/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 69, in __iter__
    obj = model_cls.from_db(db, init_list, row[model_fields_start:model_fields_end])
  File "/path/to/myproj/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 515, in from_db
    new = cls(*values)
  File "/path/to/myproj/moderation/models.py", line 66, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/path/to/myproj/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 505, in __init__
    post_init.send(sender=cls, instance=self)
  File "/path/to/myproj/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 180, in send
    return [
  File "/path/to/myproj/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 181, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "/path/to/myproj/moderation/fields.py", line 90, in post_init
    self._deserialize(value))
  File "/path/to/myproj/moderation/fields.py", line 54, in _deserialize
    obj = next(obj_generator).object
  File "/path/to/myproj/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djmoney/serializers.py", line 55, in Deserializer
    for inner_obj in PythonDeserializer([obj], **options):
  File "/path/to/myproj/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/serializers/python.py", line 146, in Deserializer
    raise base.DeserializationError.WithData(e, d['model'], d.get('pk'), field_value)
django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: ['“F(view_count) + Value(1)” value must be an integer.']: (poll.poll:pk=10) field_value was 'F(view_count) + Value(1)'
```

What is the meaning of this cryptic error (the value I am passing [1], is clearly an integer). How do I resolve this issue?

**[[Edit]]**

I did some additional investigation in the debug console, to see what was actually been returned by the expression `F('field_name') + 1`

Here are the results:

```
my_object.view_count   # This is immediately after the assignment `F() + var`
<CombinedExpression: F(view_count) + Value(1)>
my_object.save()       # Saving to see if exception thown (none thrown)
None
photo.view_count       # Checking to see what on earth is stored in the field
<CombinedExpression
```

So, it seems either the django documentation is *WRONG*, or I am misunderstanding how to increment field values safely - it would have probably been quicker to write a SP in the db directly, or even write a thread safe class to deal with this -it really shouldn't be this difficult to do this.

Comment: It was explained in the docs [`here`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#f-assignments-persist-after-model-save) as also shared by @4140tm 's answer

Answer (score 1):

Converting my comment to an answer to add more context.

Is it possible the initial value of view_count is not an integer? None for example?

Also, from the stack trace I see there are more custom methods executing after `__update_fields`. If more operations are performed on the `view_count` of current instance there, it could be problematic because of [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#f-assignments-persist-after-model-save). Basically, the value of `view_count` will be `<CombinedExpression: F(view_count) + Value(1)>` if the same python instance is used later on.

You might need to refresh the instance from database after saving.

Comment: Hmm, this is quite frustrating - especially, as I am doing everything suggested in the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#avoiding-race-conditions-using-f). To address the points you made: **1.** The initial value of the database field is (integer) zero.  **2.** I am using the if statement since Python has no select; the logic flow through just  one segment, (no further processing occurs after that branch - other than the final `save()` method.  Thanks for trying though.

Comment: This answer and the link shared seems to explain the issue. In the receiver, getting the instance again from the db should fix this problem

Comment: "Basically, the value of view_count will be <CombinedExpression: F(view_count) + Value(1)>" **This indeed, seems to be the crux of the problem**. However, how do I save this to the database? It is no good updating the instance, and not being able to save to the database. When I attempt to save to the database, that is when the error is thrown, because obviously, the Db is expecting an integer not a CombinedExpression value. :/

Comment: The problem does not occur when you save to db (as evidenced by your shell snippet). It occurs at a later point as more operations are performed. As stated in the docs, to get back the actual field value from db, you can do `<instance>.refresh_from_db()`. So, after `self.save()` in `__update_fields` do `self.refresh_from_db()`

Comment: It looks like the save method on current model invokes the save method of another one
```
File "/path/to/myproj/social/models.py", line 947, in __update_fields
    self.save()
  File "/path/to/myproj/poll/models.py", line 97, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```
Is this a parent? What happens there? You might need to do some reorganization if you can't get to `self.refresh_from_db()` (I see you've updated the example).

If you repeat the steps from the shell snippet; do `my_object.refresh_from_db()` and `my_object.view_count`, you'll see the correct value

Answer (score 0):

try `Value(F('view_count') + 1, output_field=IntegerField())`. This might work.

Comment: I'm now getting the error: _"ProgrammingError("can't adapt type 'CombinedExpression_

Comment: can you add the whole query